# $(a_1^q+a_2^q+\cdots+a_n^q)^p\gt n^{p-q}(a_1^p+a_2^p+\cdots+a_n^p)^q$

Tags: inequality

**Ques**

If $a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n$ be all positive real numbers , prove that

$(a_1^q+a_2^q+\cdots+a_n^q)^p\gt n^{p-q}(a_1^p+a_2^p+\cdots+a_n^p)^q$ , where $p,q$ are rational numbers and $0\lt{p}\lt{q}$.

**My try**

Theorem : If  $a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n$ be $n$ positive real numbers and $m$ be rational number, then

$\frac{a_1^m+a_2^m+\cdots+a_n^m}{n}\ge$ or $\le\bigl(\frac{a_1+a_2+\cdots+a_n}{n}\bigl)^m$

according as $m$ does not or does lie between $0$ and $1$.

Case 1 : Let $0\lt{p}\lt{q}\lt1$

Therefore using this theorem, when $m=p$, we get

$\frac{a_1^p+a_2^p+\cdots+a_n^p}{n}$$\le\bigl(\frac{a_1+a_2+\cdots+a_n}{n}\bigl)^p$

$\biggl(\frac{a_1^p+a_2^p+\cdots+a_n^p}{n}\biggl)^q\le \biggl(\frac{a_1+a_2+\cdots+a_n}{n}\biggl)^{pq}$

Similarly when $m=q$, we get,

$\biggl(\frac{a_1^q+a_2^q+\cdots+a_n^q}{n}\biggl)^p\le \biggl(\frac{a_1+a_2+\cdots+a_n}{n}\biggl)^{pq}$

I am stuck. Please give me some hint. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Writing $r=p/q > 1$ and $b_k=a_k^q$, the inequality is equivalent to $$\left(\frac{b_1+\cdots+b_n}{n}\right)^r\leq\frac{b_1^r + \cdots + b_n^r}{n}. $$ This is precisely the consequence of the [Jensen's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality).

Comment: Try reformulating the inequality in terms of $b_i$  where $b_i = a_i^p$

@Sangchul Lee just beat me to it !

Comment: I think I mistakenly switched the role of $p$ and $q$ in my original comment. (Perhaps I drank too much stout.) You would want to substitute $b_k=a_k^p$ and $r=q/p$.

Comment: Both the problem statement and the theorem you attempted to use are special cases of the same [generalized means inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_mean#Definition).

Comment: **Hint**: >\If $\;p<q,\quad M_p(a_1,, \dots,a_n) \le M_q(a_1,\dots,a_n) $, and the equality is true if & only if $\;a_1=\dots=a_n$.